# Getting nil when change storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a mini e-commerce on iOS, and I found an issue with my code.

I show the products on the first screen, and when the user taps on an item, it would be shown in another screen with his data.

I get this error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I suppose that my code tries to set values to the outlets before the screen loads.

My code:

*FeedOculosTableView.swift*

```
class FeedOculosTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let cellId = "cellId"

var oculosFeed: OculosFeed?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    oculosFeed = OculosFeed()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueDetalhes" {
        if let oculosDetalhe = segue.destination as? FeedOculosDetalhesViewController {
            let selectedOculos = self.oculosFeed?.oculos[(sender as! IndexPath).section]?.1[(sender as! IndexPath).row]
            oculosDetalhe.oculos = selectedOculos
        }
    }
}

/*
 methods for personalize the table
 */

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FeedOculosTableViewCell

    cell.oculos = oculosFeed?.oculos[indexPath.section]?.1[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueDetalhes", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
}
```

*FeedOculosDetalhesViewController.swift*

```
class FeedOculosDetalhesViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nomeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var precoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descricaoLabel: UILabel!

var oculos: Oculos? {
    didSet {
        nomeLabel.text = oculos?.nome // error on this line
        precoLabel.text = "R$ \(String(describing: oculos?.preco))"
        descricaoLabel.text = oculos?.descricao
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
}
```

Comment: What line in your code is causing the error?

Comment: nomeLabel.text = oculos?.nome // when I debug, nomeLabel is defined as nil

Comment: @Igor Custodio is the data saved properly?

Comment: instated of loading  data on didSet can you try on viewDidload

Comment: Now I am using fake data, FeedOculos class init returns a dictionary with the data and I show it on the table view. The problem come when user taps on an item :(

Comment: Why are you calling performSegue on a background thread? That can't be safe.

Comment: @IgorCustodio what is error on tap?

Comment: @Bapu it works! There are another way to do this or it's the best way?

Comment: @TusharSharma when I tap on a table cell and the segue is performed, I get a **nil** on the outlets of new VC

Comment: @IgorCustodio handling this in viewDidLoad is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @IgorCustodio think to load data viewDidload/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear are the best place to do..

Comment: Thanks for support!